# What is happening when a user-defined type is cast to a char*?

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, file-writing, file-read

I came across a lesson where we used a user-defined type called "Person" that stores a person's name in a char array and age as an integer.  The lesson was on writing and reading binary files.  The main program looks like this:

```
int main()
{
Person anil("anil",24); //initialize with name and age

fstream file("person.bin", ios::binary | ios::in | ios::out | ios::trunc);

if (!file.is_open())
    cout << "Error while opening file.";
else
{
    file.write((char*)&anil, sizeof(Person));
    file.seekg(0); // go back to beginning

    Person anjali;  //declare new person object

    //first argument is memory block, second argument is byte size
    file.read((char*)&anjali, sizeof(Person));

    anil.whoAreYou();  //outputs the name and age
    anjali.whoAreYou();
}

return 0;
}
```

I don't understand what is happening with these lines:

```
file.write((char*)&anil, sizeof(Person));
file.read((char*)&anjali, sizeof(Person));
```

I understand the write and read functions of fstream require the memory_block as the first argument...can someone explain what exactly is happening when the reference to the user-defined type is cast to a char * ?

Comment: It's probably a bad idea to just dump memory to disk and think that has any hope of working later. That could contain pointers or structures like `std::string` that store data elsewhere. Try writing a proper serialization method as `operator<<` so you can do `file << anil`.

Comment: *The lesson was on writing and reading binary files.* -- Aha!  Where is this bad "lesson" being taught?  I ask this, since there has to be thousands of posts here where the poster writes code exactly like this, and can't understand why their program doesn't work.  I surmised that someone, some book, or some website, is feeding this information to newbie C++ coders.

Comment: I had a feeling this was bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C/C++, `char *` is often used as a generic type of data since it always points to 1 byte. The casting code `(char*)&anil` in your code gets the pointer to `anil` with `&` and casts that to a pointer to `char`s. It writes that sequence of `char`s to the file and then reads it back into an the memory for `anjali`.

This does an exact memory copy, which causes issues if you have a pointer to somewhere else in that memory as that pointer will nearly never be valid when loading the object back. This may serve as a bit of an example, but real-world serialization is quite tricky and is often best left to some sort of serialization library. Hand serialization is possible, but that should only be done very carefully in a library or such.

If you wish to do this hand serialization, you need to determine a format for your serialization and write the base values to the file. You'll also need to determine if you actually want binary serialization or if text-based serialization would be better suited. In most cases, writing an object to a file format like JSON is a bit easier and also has the advantage of being portable between languages and human readable.

Comment: I don't know if casting to and back the file, specially from different platforms compiled with different compilers, could cause alignment issues. At least, perform an `static_cast`.

Comment: Yeah that definitely could be the case. I didn't even consider the alignment/ordering issues that could occur with different compilers. I would imagine that such issues could occur based on compilation options even on the same machine with the same compiler.  But the method of blindly casting to `char *` and writing is likely to cause issues even in the simplest cases anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`std::fstream` is derived from `std::istream` wich is basically a typedef of `basic_istream<T>` with `char as T`.

So, `fstream::read` expects a char pointer as the first argument and the cast is converting the starting address of `anil` to a `char*`.Since `sizeof(char) == 1` on most systems this is essential copying the contents of the the Person instance byte by byte to the address provided.

This is not portable nor maintainable in the long run, especially if you have pointer as member variables in your classes since you would essentially serialize the raw memory addresses of your variables.